# Cypress session erratic behavior

Tags: session, cypress

I have this very simple test in which I attempt to set some stuff as a host and then check them as guest. So I do it as follows:

I setup a session in the describe block as follows:

```
describe("Test", () => {
  const signup = (name) => {
    cy.session(name, () => {
      cy.signUp();
    });
  };
```

And then later I start the test signing up a host like

```
signup("host");
```

I do stuff as host that I later want to check with a guest.
So I manually sign off and do:

```
signup("guest");
```

And check stuff as guest.

But for some reason I don't understand the host session remains sometimes. Not always.
I don't know why this happens and I suspect I may be using cy.session the wrong way, but then why does it work every now and then?

Comment: We've experienced very unreliable cy.session() and cy.origin() logic also .. unfortunately wasn't able to make it behave fully deterministic so our tests are still flaky 20% of the time